# Making sh script executable

Tags: xubuntu, executable, sh

In Xubuntu I have marked the .sh file as executable, but it still opens in mousepad, and there is no "execute" button on right click, just "open with", I can execute the script only by dragging it in terminal, I would like to execute it by doubleclick.

Comment: It sounds like you're script is already executable. The issue is with your file manager. Look I'm it's preference.

Comment: @karel The target does not deal with Xubuntu, does it?

Comment: The terminal commands do not depend on the desktop environment that is installed.

Comment: @karel it really can. say it wants to open a new terinal tab and run commands therin. the syntax won't be the same from DE to DE and you have to write if cases for that.

Comment: See: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7779